# OnClick crashando app, em conexão com banco de dados

Tags: android, okhttp

Olá. Estou desenvolvendo um app simples com login e senha, mas sempre está ocorrendo problemas ao tentar logar. Vale dizer que estou utilizado o OkHttp.

Este é Java:

```
EditText txt_Email, txt_Pass;
TextView reg;
Button btn_Login;

String url = "";
String parametros = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

    txt_Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    txt_Pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btn_Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    reg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent abreCadastro = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, SplashScreen.class);
            startActivity(abreCadastro);
        }
    });

    /*btn_Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });*/

}

public void ClickLogin(View view){
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        String email = txt_Email.getText().toString();
        String senha = txt_Pass.getText().toString();

        if(email.isEmpty() || senha.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Preencha todos os dados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            url = "http://meudominio.host.com/login.php?email=" + email + "&senha=" + senha;
            parametros = url;
            new SolicitaDados().execute(url);
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Falha de Conexão", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return Conector.postDados(urls[0], parametros);
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {
        reg.setText(resultado);
        if(resultado.contains("login_ok")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Efetuado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dados Incorretos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}


/*@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}*/
```

Este é o XML da Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    tools:context="com.axis.guardiao.LoginScreen">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Senha"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="ClickLogin"
            android:text="Logar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cadastre-se gratuitamente"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Este é o erro:

> 06-05 18:36:47.882 5005-5005/com.axis.guardiao E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                    Process: com.axis.guardiao, PID: 5005
>                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
>                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
>                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither
>   user 10071 nor current process has
>   android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
>                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
>                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
>                                                                        at
>   android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:1170)
>                                                                        at
>   android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:745)
>                                                                        at com.axis.guardiao.LoginScreen.ClickLogin(LoginScreen.java:55)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
>                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguinte, percebi que eu não havia colocado a permissão de acesso ao status da internet, basta abrir o arquivo AndroidManifest.xml e adicionar a seguinte linha

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

O arquivo se encontra no diretório "Manifest/AndroidManifest.xml"